# A relation with geodesics on surfaces of revolution

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S$ be a surface of revolution, 
$$\varphi : (s,\theta ) \longmapsto (f(s)\cos \theta , f(s) \sin \theta , h(s)),$$
with $(f')^2+(h')^2 \neq 0$ and $f>0$. And let $\gamma : t \mapsto (\varphi (s(t),\theta (t))$ a geodesic of $S$.

> Show that $f^2(s(t))\theta'(t)=\mathrm{constant}$ for every $t$.

First I would like to point out that I found a topic pretty close from this one. Here is the [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/27555/geodesics-on-a-surface-of-revolution).

The differential of $\varphi$,
$$\mathrm{D}\varphi(s,\theta)=\left( 
\begin{array}{cc}
f'(s)\cos \theta & -f(s)\sin \theta \\
f'(s)\sin \theta & f(s)\cos \theta \\
h'(s)            & 0 
\end{array}
\right)$$ 
has its rank grower or equal than $2$ because $f>0$ and $(f')^2+(h')^2 \neq 0$ so  $S$ is a regular surface.

I had no idea how I should start so I used that $\gamma''(t)\perp\mathrm{T}_{\gamma(t)}S$ because $\gamma$ is a geodesic. In particular $\gamma'(t)\in\mathrm{T}_{\gamma(t)}S$ so
$$<\gamma''(t),\gamma'(t)>=0.$$
Then I made this relation explicit hopping to find a way to prove that $f^2(s(t))\theta'(t)$ is constant at the end.

We have
$$\gamma(t)=\varphi (s(t),\theta(t))=(\underbrace{f(s(t))\cos(\theta(t))}_{:=\gamma_1(t)},\underbrace{f(s(t))\sin(\theta(t))}_{:=\gamma_2(t)},\underbrace{h(s(t))}_{:=\gamma_3(t)}) $$

It comes
$$\gamma_1'(t)=s'(t)f'(s(t))\cos(\theta(t))-f(s(t))\theta'(t)\sin(\theta(t))$$
\begin{align*}
\gamma_1''(t)= &f(s(t))\left[ -\theta''(t)\sin(\theta(t))-(\theta'(t))^2\cos(\theta(t))\right]\\
+ &f'(s(t))\left[ s''(t)\cos(\theta(t))-2s'(t)\theta'(t)\sin(\theta(t)) \right]\\
+ &f''(s(t))(s'(t))^2\cos(\theta (t)) 
\end{align*}

$\hspace{1cm}$

$$\gamma_2'(t)=s'(t)f'(s(t))\sin(\theta(t))+f(s(t))\theta'(t)\cos(\theta(t))$$
\begin{align*}
\gamma_2''(t)= &f(s(t))\left[ \theta''(t)\cos(\theta(t))-(\theta'(t))^2\sin(\theta(t))\right]\\
+ &f'(s(t))\left[ s''(t)\sin(\theta(t))+2s'(t)\theta'(t)\cos(\theta(t)) \right]\\
+ &f''(s(t))(s'(t))^2\sin(\theta (t)) 
\end{align*}

$\hspace{1cm}$

$$\gamma_3'(t)=s'(t)h'(s(t))$$
$$\gamma_3''(t)=s''(t)h'(s(t))+(s'(t))^2h''(s(t))$$

All the calculations done I found
$$<\gamma''(t),\gamma'(t)>= \left[ (f'(s(t)))^2+(h'(s(t)))^2 \right]s'(t)s''(t)+\left[ f'(s(t))f''(s(t))+h'(s(t))h''(s(t)) \right](s'(t))^3+\color{red}{(f(s(t))^2\theta'(t)}\theta''(t)+f(s(t))f'(s(t))s'(t)(\theta'(t))^2 $$

We found back different interesting quantities such $(f')^2+(h')^2$ and of course $(f(s(t))^2\theta'(t)$ so I might be on the right track but I don't see what can I do more.

Any help would be greatly appreciate.

Comment: This is essentially conservation of (a component of) angular momentum. It is [Clairaut's relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clairaut%27s_relation) for surfaces of revolution. You can find this explained in most undergraduate differential geometry texts (including my own, which you can download from my profile).