# How to prove that the unit circle in the $x$-$y$ plane is a geodesic on the hyperboloid $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$?

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

Is there any way (besides a graph) to prove that the unit circle in the $x$-$y$ plane is a geodesic on the hyperboloid $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$?

Comment: Have a look at  1) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_of_revolution highlighting Clairaut's relation, and 2) http://math.stackexchange.com/q/27555

Comment: I have cancelled the tag "hyperbolic geometry" that has nothing to do in this context

Comment: What do you mean "besides a graph"?

Comment: Besides the below, one can also set up the geodesic equation for the hyperboloid in latitude-longitude coordinates and find conditions on the latitude coordinate $t$ such that the latitude circle $\{t = t_0\}$ is a geodesic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This follows from the uniqueness of geodesics and symmetry: Suppose $S \subset \Bbb R^3$ is a surface (for concreteness---there is also an abstract version of this statement) and that $S$ is symmetric across a plane $\Pi$ such that $S \cap \Pi$ is a smooth curve. Then, that curve is an (unparameterized) geodesic. There are some details to fill in, but the idea is this: Consider a geodesic $\gamma$ tangent to any vector tangent to $S \cap \Pi$. By symmetry the reflection of $\gamma$ must also be a geodesic tangent to that same vector, so by uniqueness of geodesics with given initial condition, $\gamma$ coincides with it reflection, and hence is contained in $S \cap \Pi$.